# How to apply style to option elements of select dropdown in angular js?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have a select element in HTML and it has a ng-repeat attribute of angular js to render the options available as shown in below code snippet -

```
<select id="mySelect" ng-model="dummyModel" ng-init="dummyModel=0"                
                           ng-disabled="false" style="width:200px;">
                                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="elem in list"
                                        value="{{elem.id}}">
                                    {{elem.description}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
```

I am able to set the width of select dropdown by using "style" attribute. But, I am unable to apply style to option elements. I want to set fixed width of 200 px for all option elements also. How can I do this ? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Note : I have already tried using CSS class as below,but it did not work :(

```
#mySelect*
{
 width:200px;
}
```

Also, I tried using ng-style="myOptionStyle() attribute on option tag as below, but that didnt work as well :(

```
<option ng-repeat="elem in list" value="{{elem.id}}"  
        ng-style="myOptionStyle()>
                      {{elem.description}}
</option>
```

and in angular js controller -

```
 $scope.myOptionStyle = function () {
                return { 'width': '200px;' };
            };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"How to apply style to option elements of select dropdown in angular js"* - what does angular has to do with this, isn't this what **css** is for..?!!

Comment: it'll be better if you can provide jsfiddle

Comment: Also on a side note, consider using `ng-options` to load your dropdown list instead of `ng-repeat`ing your options.

Comment: @DfrDkn select#mySelect, select#mySelect option { max-width:200px; }

Comment: @yjs.... select#mySelect, select#mySelect option { max-width:200px; }  didnt work :(

Comment: @TJ... I have writen code in angular js and want to apply style ( maybe using CSS or any other) .

Comment: @DfrDkn <style> select#mySelect, select#mySelect option { width:200px; } </style>

Comment: Use bootstrap and simply add `ng-class` to your option tag. For examply - 
 `<option ng-repeat="elem in list"
                                        value="{{elem.id}}" ng-class="form-control">`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. The OS is the one rendering the `<option>` element and not HTML, so it's more of OS-dependent.

Here is an extract from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-1):

> Except for `background-color` and `color`, style settings applied through the style object for the `option` element are ignored. In addition, style settings applied directly to individual options override those applied to the containing select element as a whole.

Comment: So, is there any workaround to apply style to option elements ?

Comment: @DfrDkn you should look into a plugin that creates dropdown using other elements

Comment: Yes, to an extent. As what @TJ mentioned, consider using plugins for that purpose.

Comment: @DfrDkn [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) is an example of a plugin that allows you to style option elements. There are many others though. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

to style HTML elements that have specific attributes or attribute values.

> option[value] { 
>       background-color: yellow; }